# Self employment taxation as a non-resident citizen

Tags: united-states, taxes, self-employment

If I don't live in the US long enough to be considered a resident (less than 150 days/year), do I still have to pay self employment tax on income that I generate while traveling (income generated under my sole prop, and sent to a US bank account from a corp based outside the US[the UK]). How would this change if the income was routed through a single member S-corp where the sole member was a non-resident US citizen?

I'm a US citizen, in case that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 4):

If you're a US citizen - residency rules do not apply to you. US citizen is a tax resident in the US by definition.

So it doesn't matter where in the world you live or earn money, if you're a US citizen - **all** of your **worldwide** income is taxed in the US.

If you're self-employed - yes, you still need to pay self employment tax (unless there's a totalization agreement with the country where you pay your social security taxes).

For that matter, the treatment is exactly the same as of any other US-based sole proprietor. The fact that your address is not in the US is of no consequence.

If you own a foreign corporation (and from your question it sounds that you do) - then it is even more complicated, more forms are required and more taxes are to be paid in the US. If you have foreign investments and pension accounts - more forms and more taxes. Beware of [PFIC rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_foreign_investment_company) biting you.

As to S-Corp - there may be other potential pitfalls there.

Also, don't forget [FBAR (form 114)](http://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Report-of-Foreign-Bank-and-Financial-Accounts-FBAR) and [FATCA (form 8938)](http://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Corporations/InformationforUSTaxpayers).

More info on how the US government punishes its citizens abroad [can be found here](http://americansabroad.org/issues/taxation/us-taxes-while-living-abroad-faq/).

I suggest discussing this with a licensed tax adviser (EA/CPA licensed in the US) and also with a tax adviser in your country of residency.